# How to give password for ssh commands in chef-recipe

Tags: ssh, passwords, chef-infra, rsync, knife

I am running a recipe on chef-server and it requires me to provide password for ssh on remote machine.
While running the recipe chef-client ask for the machine password and even if I provides the recipe wont work. Can anyone pls help me in this.
This is my recipe

```
    execute "run ssh" do
     command "rsync -avz --progress /opt/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/static root@X.X.X.X:/opt/chef/rsyncEx"
    end
```

[image]

Comment: your `-i` option is not correct. It needs to point to the key not the `known_hosts` file. You need to make sure your keys are properly set up on each server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using this stone-age technique we should try using ssh keys,
For this First generate the ssh key on remote machine on which we are going to run our recipe.

```
[root@node01 ~]# ssh-keygen
```

Remember dont give any passphrase for the key file

```
[root@node01 ~]# chmod 700 ~/.ssh
[root@node01 ~]# chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
[root@node01 ~]# ssh root@node02 'mkdir -p /root/.ssh'
[root@node01 ~]# scp /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@node02:/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
[root@node01 ~]# ssh root@node02 'chmod  700 /root/.ssh'
[root@node01 ~]# ssh root@node02 'chmod  600 /root/.ssh/*'
```

Now we can login without using password

```
[root@node01 ~]# ssh root@node02
```

Now to run any sh command from our recipe use ssh key , for my scenario while running rsync I used this

```
execute "static_backup" do
    command "rsync -avz --progress -e 'ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -C -c blowfish' /opt/tomcat7/webapps/static root@node2:/opt/chef/rsyncEx"
    only_if {node.name=='node2'} 
end
```